# Bulk register users using Parse Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, database, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

According to Parse CC's documentation, one can create users using the lines of codes found [here](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#users-signing-up).
I used that to create 5 entries and it worked fine. But when it came adding 350 users, it only registered 9 of them. I made sure usernames were unique. . Here is the code:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("generateUsers", function (request, response) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var contacts = new Array();
var userData = Parse.Object.extend("UserInfo");
var query = new Parse.Query(userData);
query.find({
      success: function(results) {
          response.success("Successfully found users.");
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
              var user = results[i];
              var username = user.get('Name_First') + user.get('Name_Last_F');
              var password = user.get('Name_Last_F');
              var email = user.get('email');
              var newUser = new Parse.User();
              newUser.set("username", username.toString().toLowerCase());
              newUser.set("password", password.toString().toLowerCase());
              newUser.set("email", email);
              newUser.set("info", user);
              newUser.signUp(null, {
              success: function(user) {
                // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
              },
              error: function(user, error) {
                // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
              }
            }); 
          }
        },
      error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
  });
});
```

Can someone please guide me how to go about bulk registering users or why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the full query should be done within 15 seconds, there's also a limitation of 3 seconds for beforeSave/afterSave.

check this Parse answer for more info:
https://www.parse.com/questions/cloud-code-limitation-and-api-calls-count